# How to prevent these two cubes to be dragged at the same time?

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

The following is a drag example: https://codepen.io/alexcheninfo/pen/vKkgkE. If you place one cube on top of another and grab the one in front, the one in the back is also dragged.

Here's the full code:

```
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('draggable', {
    init() {
      this.mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
      this.scene = this.el.sceneEl;
      this.camera = this.scene.camera;
      this.obj = this.el.object3D;

      this.scene.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
        this.mouse.x = (e.offsetX / this.scene.canvas.offsetWidth) * 2 - 1;
        this.mouse.y = -(e.offsetY / this.scene.canvas.offsetHeight) * 2 + 1;

        if (this.selected) {
          let r = new THREE.Raycaster();
          r.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera);
          let dist = this.obj.position.distanceTo(this.camera.position);
          let point = r.ray.direction.multiplyScalar(dist);
          this.el.setAttribute('position', `${point.x} ${point.y} ${point.z}`);
        }
      });

      this.scene.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
        let r = new THREE.Raycaster();
        r.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera);
        let intersected = r.intersectObject(this.el.object3D, true);
        let objPos = this.el.object3D.position;
        let camPos = this.camera.position;
        console.log(objPos.distanceTo(camPos));
        if (intersected.length) this.selected = true;
      });

      this.scene.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
        this.selected = undefined;
      });
    }
  });
</script>

<a-scene>
  <a-entity camera look-controls></a-entity>
  <a-sky src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aframevr/aframe/master/examples/boilerplate/panorama/puydesancy.jpg"></a-sky>
  <a-box color="tomato" position="-3 0 -10" draggable></a-box>
  <a-box draggable position="3 0 -5" draggable></a-box>
</a-scene>
```

How to prevent this? (e.g. only be able to drag the cube in front?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of where you put the control. You are doing many-raycasters-to-one-camera rather than one-raycaster-to-many-objects. It is easier if you have one raycaster that is aware of everything it is intersecting (and it will return objects sorted by distance). http://threejs.org/docs/api/core/Raycaster.html

How I would structure it is:

- Use the built-in raycaster component. The one on the master branch that is about to be released with 0.3.0 has an improved API. https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/raycaster.html
- Have a dragger component that depends on the raycaster component.
- Have the dragger component only intersect objects that have the `draggable` component, `draggable` class, or `data-draggable` attribute.

`<a-scene>
      <a-camera>
        <a-entity dragger></a-entity>
      </a-camera>
      <a-entity draggable></a-entity>
    </a-scene>`

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('dragger', {
  init: function () {
    // Configure raycaster.
    this.el.setAttribute('raycaster', {
      objects: '[draggable]',
      // ...
    });
  },

  tick: function () {
    // Use this.el.components.raycaster.intersectedEls
  }
});
```